# Modal box resizing in angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

So I am using a angular dialogue box, however, setting custom size for this dialogue box ruins the format inside the box.

I have created a plunkr for this. http://plnkr.co/edit/yXf1kNMqhAdo3iM8dFBy

If you look at the "save" and "cancel" buttons, they appear somewhere near center of the page even though they are part of modal-footer. This should appear at the bottom of the page.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really an angular issue but more a CSS one. The .modal-body css class specify that the max-height of the body will be 400px. In your case you have set the overall height of the dialog to 700px allocating more space than what the dialog will ever use.

One solution is for you to modify the css classes of the modal dialog as such :

```
.modal-header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height : 40px;
}

.modal-body {
  max-height: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} 

.modal-footer{
   position : absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 60px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 100%;
}
```

A fork of your plunkr with those changes is available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/QnekINr3L82LKr2R7POB